# Partition by approximated value

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to match two financial tables with currency approximations and no pk.

```
TABLE A
NAME    VALUE
Jerry   1024
Beth    2048
Jerry   1023
Beth    100

TABLE B
NAME     VALUE
Jerry    1024
Jerry    1020
Beth     2045
Beth     50
```

The result I'm looking for is something like:

```
NAME     TA      TB
Jerry    1024    1024
Jerry    1023    1020
Beth     2048    2045
Beth     null    50
Beth     100     null
```

I have tried used `row_number()` to create a "pseudo id" but couldn't find a way to tell oracle to partition by approximation of the `VALUE` field on the tables.

How would you guys approach this?

Comment: What is the condition for values in table A and B to be shown in one line ? I see that 1023 and 1020 and shown in one line for Jerry, but 100 and 50 are in different lines for Beth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does the '1023' for Jerry in "Table A" match the '1020' in "Table B" rather than the '1024' in "Table B" ?

If the reason is that the '1024' in "Table B" has already been matched to the '1024' in "Table A" then you have introduced some form of iterative process. Each iteration would need to find the best match in "Table B" for each row in "Table A", the best match in "Table A" for each row in "Table B" and then, when you have a a match that is the best for both A and B, allocate those together and take them out of the process.

Continue until an iteration doesn't come out with any more matches.